# material ui SingleExpand TreeView property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to prevent that when I click on several items, I have several items (expand: "true")

I would like that when I click on a new item, the old one goes back to its original state (expand: "false")

However, I did not find any property in the documentation to handle this.

https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/

```
{stoMenu && (
                  <TreeView
                    style={layout.menu}
                    defaultCollapseIcon={<KeyboardArrowUpIcon />}
                    defaultExpandIcon={<KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
                  >
                    {stoMenu.root.children.map(menu => {
                      return (
                        <TreeItem
                          key={menu.nodeId}
                          nodeId={menu.nodeId}
                          label={
                            <ListItem
                              style={layout.menuListItem}
                              className={menu.iconCls}
                            >
                              <ListItemText
                                style={layout.menuText}
                                primary={menu.text}
                                onClick={() => {
                                  if (menu.id === '/accueil') {
                                    this.props.history.push(menu.id);
                                  }
                                }}
                              />
                            </ListItem>
                          }
                        >
                          {menu.children.map(child => {
                            return (
                              <TreeItem
                                // style={layout.subMenuText}
                                className={classes.subMenu}
                                key={child.nodeId}
                                nodeId={child.nodeId}
                                label={child.text}
                                onClick={() => {
                                  if (child.id) {
                                    this.props.history.push(child.id);
                                  }
                                }}
                              />
                            );
                          })}
                        </TreeItem>
                      );
                    })}
                  </TreeView>
                )}
```